# TableLayout not working

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a `TableLyout` (in an XML file), that I am trying to add table rows to. Each row contains buttons whose number is controlled by a parameter.

Each time I run this code, the program exits. It supposed to be a simple task. What is going wrong?

Java:

```
public class Play extends Activity{
int status=0 , timeDelay , row , col;
TextView score;
TableRow    rows [];
TableLayout  table;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_play);

    setLevel(); 
    table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Table_cards);

    for(int i=0 ; i<row ; i++){
        TableRow tblr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int j=0 ; j<col ; j++){
            final ImageButton b = new ImageButton(this);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_back_blue);
                }
            });
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c1+j);
            tblr.addView(b);
        }
        table.addView(tblr);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/Table_cards"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_up"
    android:background="@drawable/wss"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also post the `setLevel ()` and any other supporting functions you use, and the error output.

Comment: you need to initialize the **row** and **col** variable ex:  int row=5, col=5;

Answer (score 0):

This code works well,

```
    public class Play extends Activity{
    private int status=0 , timeDelay , row=10, col=10;
    private TextView score;
    private TableRow    rows [];
    private TableLayout  table;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.table_dynamic);

//      setLevel(); 
        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for(int i=0 ; i<row ; i++){
            TableRow tblr = new TableRow(this);
            for(int j=0 ; j<col ; j++){
                final ImageButton b = new ImageButton(this);
                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                      b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_back_blue);
                    }
                });
//              b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c1+j);
                tblr.addView(b);
            }
            table.addView(tblr);
        }
    }
}
```

And layout table_dynamic,

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Comment: Sorry, I will consider this.